# WebSocket collect callbacks

Tags: javascript, websocket

```
$('#ws-show-log').click(function(){
  var webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://myhost.loc:8080');
  webSocket.onopen = function() {
    console.log('onopen');
  };
  webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
  };
  webSocket.onclose = function() {
    console.log('onclose');
  };
  webSocket.onerror = function() {
    console.log('onerror');
  };
});
```

when i click #ws-show-log - i see all messages from webSocket canal:

```
onopen
onmessage message1
onmessage message2
```

But when i click second time on #ws-show-log in console all messages are duplicated, i see:

```
onopen
onmessage message1
onmessage message1
onmessage message2
onmessage message2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to establish a connection to the websocket just once you can use jQuery's once() handler.

Use it like this

```
$('#ws-show-log').once('click', function() {
    // inner code
 }
```

If you want to establish a new connection to your server each time you click on `#ws-show-log`, then you should close the connection after you used it. Otherwise the connection will stay open and each time you click on `#ws-show-log` will result in an **extra** connection to your server.

You can close your WebSocket by using `webSocket.close();`. You could put this close function inside your `onmessage` handler. Now when you received a message from you server, the WebSocket will be closed.

You can do that like this:

```
webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
    webSocket.close();
};
```

Comment: like this?
<!-- language: lang-php -->

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
        webSocket.close();
    };

and how i get next message from Websocket?

Comment: You can get a next message each time you click on `#ws-show-log'. Because you already establish a connection to your server each time you click.

Comment: no, i click (one time) and see websocket log, i want see all messages from websocket.

Comment: Okay I have changed the answer. Look at the Once approach I think it fits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

thnx @David, but all work when close old connection, before create new.

```
var webSocket;
$('#ws-show-log').click(function(){

  if (webSocket) webSocket.close();

  webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://myhost.loc:8080');
  webSocket.onopen = function() {
    console.log('onopen');
  };
  webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('onmessage: ' + event.data);
  };
  webSocket.onclose = function() {
    console.log('onclose');
  };
  webSocket.onerror = function() {
    console.log('onerror');
  };
});
```